# Why is my unit test failing for a switch statement?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nunit

Hi I am trying to unit test the following and check that this switch/case statement works:

`DiagnosticsComponentFactory` class

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceCollection;

public IComponent Create (string name)
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case BoardItemComponent.TypeName:
            return _serviceCollection.GetService<BoardItemComponent>();
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

My `BoardItemComponent` class:

```
public class BoardItemComponent
{
    public const string TypeName = "name";

    public BoardItemComponent(IConfigurationRepository configurationRepository) : base(configurationRepository)
    {

    }
}
```

`BoardItemComponent` is derived from `IComponent`, and it's added like follows in my *Startup.cs* file:

```
services.AddScoped<IComponent, BoardItemComponent>();
```

my unit test:

```
[Test]
public void GetComponent_GivenComponentFactory_ExpectBoardComponent()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ComponentFactoryRegistration.Register(serviceCollection);
    var factory = new DiagnosticsComponentFactory(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
    var component = factory.Create("name");
    Assert.IsNotNull(component);
}
```

When I debug my unit test, `component` is *null*, despite it following all the correct steps. It goes into the switch case statement correctly and recognizes that is the correct case, however it still returns *null*.

From what I have shared (and apologies, as I know that the names in these code snippets are vague without context), is there any obvious reason that my unit test fails? I'm new when it comes to unit testing in C#.

Comment: obviously `_serviceCollection.GetService<BoardItemComponent>()` returns null for whatever reason.

Comment: The likely reason being that there is no registered service for `BoardItemComponent`

Comment: Ok thanks @AFriend - how do I rectify this?

Comment: You need to verify the value of each variable and each return value at every step of the code. Avoid having more then 1 Operation per codeline. `var factory = new DiagnosticsComponentFactory(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider())` is two. Add a ton of temporary variables to assign values too. For there Debug messages or stepping through teh steps in the debugger will get you somewhere. | There is no need to worry about performance. The JiT and Compiler Optimsiations are pretty good at cutting out underused variables in Release builds.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher I tried this and it all seems to step through fine, with everything working as it should until i get to `component` which is null ...but I cannot work out why

Comment: Did you register `IConfigurationRepository` in your DI container? If that's not there, you cannot instantiate a `BoardItemComponent` - though I would expect it to throw in that case and not just return `null`.

Comment: Hi @germi - thanks, yes it is registered in my DI container  already

Comment: Not sure how people are helping without knowing what `DiagnosticsComponentFactory` is

Comment: @DetectivePikachu the first snippet is from `DiagnosticsComponentFactory`. Note the `Create` method

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, there will be in future, although this is the only one at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments you indicated that the component is registered as

```
services.AddScoped<IComponent, BoardItemComponent>();
```

The provider is aware of the `IComponent` interface, but is asking for `BoardItemComponent` implementation

```
_serviceCollection.GetService<BoardItemComponent>();
```

The above will return `null` if the provider is unaware how to resolve `BoardItemComponent` when explicitly requested.

Register the implementation

```
services.AddScoped<BoardItemComponent>();
```

and you can also associate it with the abstraction using the factory delegate

```
services.AddScoped<IComponent>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<BoardItemComponent>());
```

Isolated testing should now be able to be done accordingly

```
[Test]
public void GetComponent_GivenComponentFactory_ExpectBoardComponent() {
    //Arrange
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<BoardItemComponent>();
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<IConfigurationRepository>(sp => Mock.Of<IConfigurationRepository>());

    var factory = new DiagnosticsComponentFactory(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());

    //Act
    var component = factory.Create(BoardItemComponent.TypeName);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(component);
}
```

Now it was indicated that there may be more implementation in the future.

Lets say for example

```
services.AddScoped<BoardItemComponent>();
services.AddScoped<AnotherItemComponent>();
```

The factory can then be refactored

```
public class DiagnosticsComponentFactory {    
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;

    public DiagnosticsComponentFactory (IServiceProvider services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public IComponent Create (string name) {
        switch (name) {
            case BoardItemComponent.TypeName:
                return services.GetRequiredService<BoardItemComponent>();
            case AnotherItemComponent.TypeName:
                return services.GetRequiredService<AnotherItemComponent>();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```